# Using PSSession, Not able to run commands on azure server

Tags: powershell, azure

Still trying to figure out how to automate a build of an azure server, and install software on it after the build.

The template referenced is our own version of the one from used is based off of the one from this one:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-winrm-windows

We only added 2016-Datacenter-smalldisk to the WindowsOSversion, to get the latest server.

From building this server, I wait to make sure it is connected to the server before connecting to the server via PSSession. I am trying to use this PSSession to install IIS, JAVA, other needed software. But anything I run after the PSSession, it still installs on my local PC.

I am coding/running this powershell script from my own pc. How do I get these items to install on the server itself?

```
# Variables for common values
$location = "East US"
$resourceGroup = "rgTest"
$vmName = "vmTest"
$subscriptionname = "snTest"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("test@here.org", $secpasswd)

# Add your Azure account to the local PowerShell environment.
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred

Write-Host "Step 0" 
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -ev notPresent -ea 0
if ($notPresent)
{
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
}
$tempsubscriptionname = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName 
$subscriptionname

Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName rgseleniumtest1 -Name saseleniumtemplates
$templateuri = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Container templates -Blob template.json -Permission r `
-ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2.0) -FullUri

Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location "East US"
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -TemplateUri $templateuri

Do {
    $Ping = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='dnsselenium.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com' AND Timeout=10000";
Start-Sleep -s 30
}
Until($Ping.IPV4Address -ne "")

$hostName=  'testtesttest.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com'
$winrmPort = '5986'

$soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("LocalAdminUser", $secpasswd)

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $cred -Port $winrmPort -SessionOption $soptions -UseSSL 

#try 1
import-module servermanager
Add-WindowsFeature web-server -IncludeAllSubFeature

try 3
# Install iis
Install-WindowsFeature web-server -IncludeManagementTools



#install Java
$InstallDir = "c:\installer"
$Destination = "c:\installer"

New-Item -Path $InstallDir -type directory -Force

#LATEST JAVA 8 JRE
$Source = "http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=211996"
$Destination = "$Destination\java.exe"
$Options = "$InstallDir\java_options.txt"

(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($Source, $Destination)

$text = 'INSTALL_SILENT=Enable
AUTO_UPDATE=Enable
REBOOT=Disable
SPONSORS=Disable
REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=Enable
'
$text | Set-Content $Options
Start-Process -FilePath $Destination -ArgumentList "INSTALLCFG=$Options /s /L $InstallDir\jre-install.log" -Wait -Verbose -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me awhile to find the answer. I got the answer from this page.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949442/running-azure-commands-over-a-pssession    . Enter-PSSession is intended for interactive mode only and not meant for scripting. A way around this is to create a New-PSSession and then use this with Invoke-Command. So I didn't know this....so basically wrapped everything in Invoke-Command

Comment: Yes, you should use `New-PSSession`, you could refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658413/new-pssession-in-an-azure-runbook-arm/43670931#43670931)about this.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved, please accept it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.